# PicklingError when running code inside function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm running a very basic `multiprocessing` command in python. 
I just tried running the following scripts in shell. One errors, one does not.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    mylist = ['Hello', 'You', 'Are', 'Human']

    def cube(x):
        return {'This': x}

    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(x,)) for x in mylist]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]

    return output


main()
```

This returns the following error(also tried with `if __name__ == '__main__'`, same error):

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Linux64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/apps/Linux64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/apps/Linux64/python2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Then I ran this one

```
mylist = ['Hello', 'You', 'Are', 'Human']

def cube(x):
    return {'This': x}

pool = Pool(processes=4)
results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(x,)) for x in mylist]
output = [p.get() for p in results]

print output
```

and i got:

```
[{'This': 'Hello'}, {'This': 'You'}, {'This': 'Are'}, {'This': 'Human'}]
```

Comment: You should put your multiprocessing code in a main function so it doesn’t get repeatedly called every time your module is imported in the new processes.

Comment: What's a DCC application? This question seems to be less about python, multiprocessing and pickle and more about DCC vs your IDE. What, if anything, happens in your DCC code before it gets to this? Are you also testing just calling this as the main entry point from the command line?

Comment: @Jack Ok, I've just run two scripts from command line. One wrapped in a main() function, and one not wrapped. The main() one returns the pickle error. I just updated the main post with the example.

Comment: @MohammedHamid Try the first option with `cube` defined outside the `main`. That is, `main` and `cube` are siblings.